# Nginx Virtual Host alternative

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, web-server

Is it possible to setup virtual hosts without using the sites-enabled and sites-available directories?  I am able to setup it up using those 2 directories but since the Centos install doesn't come with them pre installed, I figured there was another way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nginx.conf file, just include a server block for each "virtual host" you are trying to create.

Your nginx.conf file probably has an `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` line which basically says append all of the configs in that directory to the main nginx.conf file.  This is usually done so you don't have a massive nginx.conf file that you have to sort through when you have hundreds of sites.  If you don't want to create that those directories because centos doesn't make them for you, then you can just put anything that would have gone into one of those directories directly into your nginx.conf file.

```
server {
   server_name www.domain1.com;
   root /www/domain1.com;
}

server {
   server_name www.domain2.com;
   root /www/domain2.com;
}
```

Comment: I installed nginx by following a tutorial because I'm still pretty new to Linux and it told me to create the sites-enabled/available directories and to add that include line.  My buddy is a sysadmin and he told me I didn't need it, so I wanted to see what he meant.  You did a great job of explaining it, I appreciate it.  I am going to try and add virtual hosts by just adding another block like you suggested.  How did you know to do that? Is it in the documentation or was it just trial and error?  I want to be able to figure this stuff out on my own.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: It's described in the official documentation at http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration .  Also, if the answer helped, then please click the up arrow next to the answer to give it a +1 and mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I did the check but it won't let me do the up arrow because i need 15 reputation first.  As soon as I have it I will +1 it.  Thanks again.